# How to merge headers of multiple columns of a pandas dataframe in a new column if values of the multiple columns meet certain criteria

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame of size 122400*92, out of which 8 columns represent flow, which maybe in different combinations. I want to merge all the columns headers in a new column if the flow in each column is > 20.

For an example:
A Flow: 52
B Flow: 46
C Flow: 0
D Flow: 54
E Flow: 34
F Flow: 0
G Flow: 12
H Flow: 0

New column will give :'A,B,D,E,G'
I have used the below code, which seems to work for small dataset but fails to work in large dataset.

reqcol=['A FLOW','B FLOW','C FLOW','D FLOW','E FLOW','F FLOW','G FLOW','H FLOW']

```
arr=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    arr1=[]
    for j in reqcol:
        if(df[j][i]>20):
            arr1.append(j[0])
    arr.append(arr1)
df['Combination'] = arr
```

Request your help

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, can you please rework you question to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? In particular, input and output data that can be copied directly would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define some test data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
reqcol = ['A FLOW', 'B FLOW']
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4'], 'A FLOW': [5, 80,50, 40], 'B FLOW' : [10, 0, 40, 10]})
```

This gives you the following data frame:

```
>>> df
  NAME  A FLOW  B FLOW
0   N1       5      10
1   N2      80       0
2   N3      50      40
3   N4      40      10
```

First let's only look at the relevant columns:

```py
>>> df[reqcol]
   A FLOW  B FLOW
0       5      10
1      80       0
2      50      40
3      40      10
```

Now check where the flow is bigger than 20 (only in the relevant columns):

```py
>>> df[reqcol].where(lambda x: x > 20)
   A FLOW  B FLOW
0     NaN     NaN
1    80.0     NaN
2    50.0    40.0
3    40.0     NaN
```

We can now apply a function onto every row. The function will get a `Pandas.Series` Object. First we eliminate all `NaN`'s from the `Series` by calling `.dropna()` and then we get all remaining keys by using `.keys()` (original column name like `'FLOW A'`).

```py
>>> dfBigger20 = df[reqcol].where(lambda x: x > 20)
>>> dfBigger20.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().keys(), axis = 1)
0                      Index([], dtype='object')
1              Index(['A FLOW'], dtype='object')
2    Index(['A FLOW', 'B FLOW'], dtype='object')
3              Index(['A FLOW'], dtype='object')
dtype: object
```

To make this more beatiful we can convert the `Index` Object returned by `.keys()` to a regular list.

```py
>>> dfBigger20.apply(lambda row: list(row.dropna().keys()), axis = 1)
0                  []
1            [A FLOW]
2    [A FLOW, B FLOW]
3            [A FLOW]
dtype: object
```

Now all in one line and saved into the original `df`:

```
>>> df['Combinations'] = df[reqcol].where(lambda x: x>20).apply(lambda row: list(row.dropna().keys()), axis=1)
>>> df
  NAME  A FLOW  B FLOW      Combinations
0   N1       5      10                []
1   N2      80       0          [A FLOW]
2   N3      50      40  [A FLOW, B FLOW]
3   N4      40      10          [A FLOW]
```